# Constructors in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am quite new to kivy. While practicing with online examples, I noticed that many of their widget classes don't have constructors. I just want to ask what is significance of constructors in kivy widgets, n when to use them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare a constructor unless you need to do something specific. For example, our [Widget class have a constructor](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L322) that does lot of stuff, like applying the properties, create the widget canvas, apply kv rules, bind the construtor events if passed etc.

If you create a widget, but have nothing to do, there is no need to declare a constructor, the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) will determinate which one to use on the subclasses. This is the same for all Python classes.